# Conditional formatting with Index(Match), 2 conditions (vertical & horizontal)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have this data set in Excel (google sheet) Sheet1

[image: ![enter image description here]

And these targets by month by city in Sheet2

[image: ![enter image description here]

I would like that cellS AI3 to AK5 highlight if the objective of Sheet2, for the specific city and month are not reached.

I thought that writing this in the conditional format box would work but it doesn't `=AI3<INDEX(Sheet2!D:D;MATCH($A3&MONTH(AI$2);Sheet2!$A:$A&Sheet2!$C:$C;0)))`

Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When searching by two or more variables, you can use FILTER. In this case both variables appear to be in the same direction, despite your title. Try with:

```
=AI3<FILTER(Sheet2!D:D;INDIRECT("Sheet2!$A:$A");$A3;INDIRECT("Sheet2!$C:$C");MONTH(AI$2)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried, it says the formula is not valid. Is it even possible to do conditional formating with values of another sheet ?

Comment: You can, with INDIRECT. Try with the update!

Answer (score 0):

Your first index argument should have $ as it will "move" to `E` and `F` for `AJ` and `AK` otherwise, so `Sheet2!D:D` -> `Sheet2!$D:$D` . But actually it doesn't matter in this exact case (would matter in Excel) because if you want to refer to other sheets in conditional formatting in google sheets, you need to use `INDIRECT`.

Formula:

```
=AI3<INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet2!$D:$D");MATCH($A3&MONTH(AI$2);INDIRECT("Sheet2!$A:$A")&INDIRECT("Sheet2!$C:$C");0))
```

Applied to `AI3:AK5`

Result:

[image]